# how do i include a if else question in my code on visual c++

Tags: c++

I'm new to coding, and for my first project I wanted to do something useful and wrote a code that calculates your grade at the end of the year (only works in Germany).

My problem is that some students have 15 classes and some 16, and I want to include an `if` option, but I don't know how. Could someone help me?

Here is the code:

```cpp
//#include <iostream> verstehe ich nicht ?  

#include <iostream>  

float average(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h, int i, int j, int k, int l, int m, int n, int o) 
{

    //return sorgt für das Rechnen und wiederholen der "Probleme"  

    return (float)(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o)/15;

}

//int main ist die Hauptfunktion der Sitzung 
int main()
{
    //int num (Variable) z.B num1 steht für anzahl der Probleme : /(Problem Fach)\

    int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10, num11, num12, num13, num14, num15;

    //float ist der Wert und avg = average   

    float avg;

    //printf zeigt das Fach, und den Bereich der eingetragen werden soll  

    printf("Deutsch: ");  
    //scanf nimmt die ganzzahligen Werte von printf (z.B. Deutsch = 3)   
    scanf_s("%d", &num1);

    printf("Mathe: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num2);

    printf("English: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num3);

    printf("Biologie: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num4);
    //bei / ist das fach anzukreuzen, welches auf den Schüler zutrifft  
    printf("Kunst/Musik: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num5);

    printf("Chemie: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num6);

    printf("Geschichte: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num7);

    printf("Physik: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num8);

    printf("GK: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num9);

    printf("Sport: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num10);

    printf("Geographie: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num11);

    printf("Ev./KAth.Rel/Ethik: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num12);

    printf("Französisch/Latein/Polnisch : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num13);

    printf("Informatik: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num14);

    printf("Kunst/Musik: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num15);
  
    avg = average(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10, num11, num12, num13, num14, num15);
    //%.2f benutzt man um 2 Nachkommastellen der Endnote anzuzeigen!  
   
    printf("Der Durchschnitt dieser Noten: %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, beträgt: %.2f", num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10, num11, num12, num13, num14, num15, avg);
    //return 0; raffe ich auch nicht xD  
    {
        system("pause");     
    }   

    return 0;

} //{ und } schließen die "Funktionen" ab bzw. die Gruppen der Funktionen
```

Comment: It seems you should learn how to use arrays.

Comment: Also learn about `for` loops.

Comment: Also, if the comments in the code are supposed to tell us anything, please translate them into English, otherwise, remove them.

Comment: Sieht immerhin nach C aus, keep on learning. Your comments tell me you misunderstood several things. hint: mostly commands do exactly what they are named for. return - returns stuff.. it doesnt calculate. The formula behind calculates, return just gives the result back. float is not the value, value named avg is of type float.

Comment: @Jakob "_not important for us_" - I translated a few comments and I found them useful. Not to understand the code but to understand OP and I find that useful too sometimes when thinking about answerering a question.

Comment: You've come to the right place for this question. Keep learning. Never stop learning. Arrays and a "for loop" would help. I believe Remy has already provided a sample in his answer below. Give it a try and keep asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prompt the user if there is a 16th class. If there is, read that score. Put all of the scores into an `int[16]` array and pass it to the `average()` function, along with a parameter indicating how many `int` values are in the array. Loop through the array that many times to calculate the average, and when printing the values.

```cpp
#include <iostream>  
#include <cstdlib>

float average(int scores[], int numScores)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numScores; ++i) {
        total += scores[i];
    }
    return (float)(total) / numScores;
}

int main()
{
    const char* classNames[] = {
        "Deutsch", "Mathe", "English", "Biologie", "Kunst/Musik",
        "Chemie", "Geschichte", "Physik", "GK", "Sport",
        "Geographie", "Ev./KAth.Rel/Ethik", "Französisch/Latein/Polnisch", "Informatik", "Kunst/Musik"
    };

    int scores[16] = {};
    int numScores = 15;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        std::cout << classNames[i] << ": ";
        std::cin >> scores[i];
    }

    std::cout << "Andere? [yn]: ");
    char input;
    std::cin >> input;

    if (input == 'Y' || input == 'y') {
        std::cout << "Ergebnis: ");
        std::cin >> scores[15];
        ++numScores;
    }

    float avg = average(scores, numScores);
   
    std::cout << "Der Durchschnitt dieser Noten: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < numScores; ++i) {
        std:cout << scores[i] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "beträgt: " << avg;

    std::system("pause");     
    return 0;
}
```